# SyntaxError: playlist.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, rspec

hate to ask this, but i can't for he life of me find this end error, can anyone help> please, thanks.

```
require_relative 'playlist'

describe playlist do

    before do
      @playlist = Playlist.new("kermit")
    end


    context "being played with one movie" do
      before do
        @initial_rank= 10
        @Movie = Movie.new("goonies", @initial_rank)
        @playlist.add_movie(@movie)
      end

      it "give the movie a thumbs up if high number is rolled" do
        @playlist.play(5)

        @movie.rank.should == @initial_rank + 1
      end

      it "skips the movie if a medium niumber is rolled" do
        @playlist.play(3)

        @movie.rank.should == @initial_rank  
      end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is line 33? The syntax is ok of the code you posted.

Comment: exactly, there is no line 33

Comment: I am not sure that it is source of problem but... change `describe Playlist do` (you describe class!)

Comment: ah good call, but no, not the problem.

Comment: Try remove all tests - leave require_relative and `describe Playlist do end`. do you have syntax error? if yes - analyze result of `require_relative 'playlist'`

Comment: yup tried that, (good idea again!), and got right down to the require_relative, still didn't work, then, it only worked with nothing! on the page, then i realized its the class file , not this one :-(

Comment: i had 2 files loaded in the text editor, thanks mate :-)